# How to use curl in wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, api, curl, woocommerce

i wanted to apply the API settings of woocommerce in wordpress so its like i wanted to get the list of customers in my site. however there was a curl command which i am not familiar on where to place this command. I hope you can help me out

```
curl https://example.com/wc-api/v2/customers \ -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

i got this from wootheme site http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#view-list-of-customers

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure woocommerce in the following ways

1. Enable Rest API in woocommerce setting
2. Set custom permalink structure other than default in wordpress settings
3. Generate API KEYs for user in edit user

Some other approach i would suggest:

- Create a custom plugin this will help you to keep the working easy for you.
- Add API Client Library in your custom plugin. (API Client Library is where the rather than using the curl you can user functions which are user friendly)
- Use API Client Library function and access the data you want explore the library for the function which are defined in it.

For more details you need to go through links like which will help you achieve you purpose.

http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2014/02/10/woocommerce-rest-api-client-library/